# Is there a way to set an event on all class/object functions where a listener will receive function name and parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, dom-events

Is there a way to set an event on all class/object functions where a listener will receive function name and parameters?

I want to be able to run some functionality anytime a function is called that is part of that regular object or class.

The purpose of this, and I may be going down a complicated path, is to assign object level caching for a function.  So say I have a service function that calls a nodejs sequelize method, I'd like to cache it for x minutes, for example.  The listener above would therefore write to redis with a ttl and check redis anytime the function is called.

I did this with Scala with no boilerplate code using annotations to denote ttl for any method and macros for that boring set and get to redis.  Not sure how to accomplish that using Javascript / nodejs.

Sorry in advance if this is an inappropriate stack overflow question, but any general direction would help.

Comment: Calling a function doesn't trigger an event. You can monkey-patch the function to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [aspect oriënted programming](https://medium.com/@blueish/an-introduction-to-aspect-oriented-programming-5a2988f51ee2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern approach to doing this with JavaScript is through a Proxy Object.  Here is the description of them from the docs:

> The Proxy object is used **to define custom behavior for fundamental
>   operations** (**e.g.** property lookup, assignment, enumeration, **function
>   invocation**, etc).

Here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for a decorator (which are currently [Stage 2 Draft](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/), so not yet part of the language).

However - using a Proxy you can create something like that:

```js
class MyClass {
  func1() {
    console.log('run func1');
  }
  func2() {
    console.log('run func2');
  }
}

m = new MyClass();

var p = new Proxy(m, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
      if (typeof target[name] == 'function') {
        console.log('wrapper on', name);
        return target[name]
      }
    }
});

p.func1();
p.func2();
```